# Facing 401 Error while streaming tweets using python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

The below image shows the code and error message .

I have pasted the code below

Code:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener


#consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey=""
csecret=""
atoken=""
asecret=""

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        return(True)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car","python"])
```

Sample Image:
Please help me I am stuck with this for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this software but I believe the problem is that you haven't supplied a consumer key and consumer secret. This being the case you could refer to,

[Getting twitter consumer key and secret](http://support.yapsody.com/hc/en-us/articles/203068116-How-do-I-get-a-Twitter-Consumer-Key-and-Consumer-Secret-key-)